# iOS: Thirdparty Frameworks for Socket Communication available

Tags: ios, sockets, stream

my Task is to send the G-Sensor Data nearly in realtime from an iOS Device to an Application running on a different Device (OSX, iOS, maybe Windows). From all I've read so far, a Socketstream seems to be the best choice for this kind of Task. Do you agree?
My Question is, since I have no experience in Socket programming, are there any third party Frameworks that make socket programming more easier? Maybe that they already created something that will reconnect after the connection was lost and such things like Error Handling? I guess that not everyone invents the wheel again while programming with sockets?

Thank you for any kind of information regarding this topic.

twickl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly consider [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).  It has very much all the callbacks you will need.  There are also a version for Tcp and UDP as well.